# How to detemine I am facing the node

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-location

I am planning to develop a map navigation system. Suppose that I stay in the blue color node and face the arrow direction. I hope that I can notify user when they are facing in red node. Therefore, how to detect whether user facing red node?

I know the blue color and red color nodes location, as well as the compass angle.

[image]

Comment: What did you try? show your code and explain the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just treat the blue dot at the origin. The vector of (red-blue) will give you an angle. If. this angle is same as compass angle,blue is facing red.

The angle could be computed as:`acos((red.x- blue.x)/ hypot(red.x - blue.x , red.y - blue.y))` This result will give you [0, Pi]